# Set jQuery UI DatePicker on Inputs inside iFrame

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, datepicker

I have an `index` page which loads an `iFrame` with content based on what link you click.

Some of the content includes an `input` with `type="dated"` whenever a user needs to input a date.
I'm trying to take advantage of that, and bind a `datepicker` to all those inputs.

The `datepicker` control displays whenever I select the `input`, however when I try select a Date I get the following error:
`Missing instance data for this datepicker`

Here is my implementation:

```
var $frameBody = $('#frmContent').contents().find('body');

$.each($frameBody.find('[type="dated"]').datepicker(), function (i, e) {
    if (e.length > 0) {
         $(e).datepicker();
    }
});
```

Note: I've moved it into an `$.each` loop because of other potential fixes I found

Comment: I did some digging and came up with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/k21vrscv/). The problem is that `datepicker` adds it's markup to your main page and not in iframe itself. And when internally it tries to find the input it's attached to, it fails because it looks for the input on main document and not inside iframe (thus showing the error message you see). I have no answer on this unfortunately, just my research results.

Comment: Thanks for this! At least I know now it isn't something specifically I did wrong on my end - I just went ahead and set `datepicker` in every `iFrame`

Comment: Well, your `$.each` part still seems strange, I'd use simple `$frameBody.find('[type="dated"]').datepicker();`. As for iframe - I guess your final solution is the only way.

Comment: I did have what you just mentioned - But through digging of my own I got informed to check that the element isn't null